# Postgresql cross-database references in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a search for and got stuck on a cross-database references error

```
activities = Activity.order(:name).includes([:profile => :country])
activities = activities.where("lower(activities.city) like ?", "%#{params[:activity_search][:city].downcase}%") unless params[:activity_search][:city] == ""      
activities = activities.where("activities.sport_id =?", params[:activity_search][:sport_id])
```

I'm trying to add something like this:

```
activities = activities.where("activities.profiles.country.id =?", params[:activity_search][:country_id])
```

an activity's country is the same as the activity creator's country.

How can I add this constraint in my query?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `joins` here to include the associations:

```
activities.joins(profiles: :country).where('countries.id = ?', params[:whatever])
```

This assumes `Activity has_many :profiles` and `Profile has_one :country` and `countries` is your table name, but I think all that is true based on your post. This will include the associated `profiles` and `country` with `activities` and allow you to use their attributes in the `where` method call.